# Recovering pixels at intersection of polygon and raster image in PyQGIS?

Tags: pyqgis, pixel

I am beginner in PyQGIS.

I would like to recover the pixels that intersect with my shapefile (polygon) using a loop for ... apparently, the loop is incorrect (no result).

Below the code

```
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from osgeo import gdal
from osgeo.gdalconst import *

#driver = gdal.GetDriverByName ('GTiff')
Driver.Register # ()

rlayer = "F:\ MASTER GEOM \ MasterGeomatic_data \ PLEIADES \ PLEIADES_20130415_COLNAT.TIF"
rlayer = gdal.Open (rlayer, GA_ReadOnly)
provider = QgsVectorLayer ("F: try1.shp", 'try', 'ogr')
extent = provider.extent ()

collars = rlayer.RasterXSize
rows = rlayer.RasterYSize
#print (passes)
#print (rows)
val = []
for range (cols) in extent:
     print (range)
```

Comment: Your code is not PyQGIS and it has many problems.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a proposed solution using QGIS & a simple python script that gets the data as [NumPy](http://www.numpy.org) array.
First, to get the raster area that intersects with your polygon shapefile, I suggest using the QGIS tool (via the interface) called [Clip Raster by mask layer](https://docs.qgis.org/2.6/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/gdalogr/gdal_extraction/cliprasterbymasklayer.html). Here is how the output raster of that tool can look like:

*Before:*
[image: Raster with sample polygon]
*After*
[image: Output Raster]

Now your output raster contains *just* the values for the polygon area, with all the rest being 'No data' (understand the difference between 0 and no data!). 
To simply get the data as a [NumPy](http://www.numpy.org) array (including the NoData), use the following script:

```
import gdal 
import numpy as np

rlayer = "C:\\Data\\Clipped_Raster.tif"
rast_data_source = gdal.Open(rlayer)

#Get metadata (optional)
print 'Number of bands: ', rast_data_source.RasterCount
cols = rast_data_source.RasterXSize
rows = rast_data_source.RasterYSize
print 'Size: ', cols, rows

srcband = rast_data_source.GetRasterBand(1)

data = srcband.ReadAsArray(0,0,cols,rows)

for pixel in data:
     #do something with the data
```